# How to programmatically adjust a folder of audio files so they are all about the same loudness?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, html5-audio

I have a website that collects audio recordings from visitors using Flash, I am using ffmpeg2theora to convert the files from FLV to OGG...because I am re-using the files for an HTML5 Web page (OGG is supported on Firefox and Chrome). But, some files are loud and some are really quiet.

Is there a way to make all the files sound about the same loudness? It's OK if the quality is poorer for the quieter audio files, just as long as it's easier to hear the message that someone has left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called normalisation, you can do it in bulk with many players like [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/download) (which calls it [replaygain](http://www.techspot.com/tweaks/foobar/)) or other audio software. At it simplest it makes the loudest sample in a song 100% and the softest 0% then averages out everything in between. Something like replaygain goes a step further and allows you to sample across a whole albulm or set of files which is useful in cases where certain tracks on are album are supposed to be quieter than others (like a ballad vs a rock track).

If you really do mean to do it programmically then [foobar2000 can also be scripted](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=22055).

For a more linux-friendly solution you may also like [Normalize](http://normalize.nongnu.org/)

```
normalize *.ogg
```

EDIT: It occurs to me that replaygain may not be the best choice since it requires a compatible player and there is no guarentee HTML5 players will be. I'd use Normalise (see comment).

Comment: Great, thanks! I also found a program called vorbisgain, does that do the same thing?

Comment: Almost, though vorbisgain focuses on 'perceptual loudness' which is not how loud something is but how loud it seems to be (due to peculiarity in human ear etc). The catch however is that vorbisgain and replaygain adjust headers in the files rather than the file contents which only works if your player uses those headers (and html5 players may not). i'd stick with normalize for your needs.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried "normalize" but it looks like the latest version doesn't support OGG. There is a comment in 2002 that OGG will be supported in version 0.8, but the latest version as of 2005 is 0.7.7.

Comment: Most examples I've found do it stages. ie, FLV -> WAV -> Normalize -> OGG however I suspect you could simplify this by using mencoder like this: `mencoder -ovc null -af volnorm=1 -oac vorbis input.flv -o output.ogg`. Please note I haven't tested that example, you may need to play around with it a bit

Comment: actually that doesn't work at all, it seems that disabling video requires a hack, vorbis audio has to go through -oac lavc and even then it fails for me complaining about experiment features being disabled. I suspect it'll just be far easier to do it in seperate steps.

Comment: Good tip about doing the normalization with WAV files. I don't mind the extra steps as long as it works. Thanks!

Comment: Note about using foobar2000, I had to remove the first stream using: "ffmpeg -i INPUT.ogg -map 0:1 -codec:a copy -codec:v copy OUTPUT.mpg" before foobar2000 would open my OGG files. Not sure why, though. My guess is that it has something to do with the ffmpeg2theora conversion (*.flv to *.ogg). Maybe because I am not using video, just audio.

Comment: Just a final follow-up. I got this working the way SpliFF suggested above, by converting the files to WAV (and I had to use the "-f wav" option). Then, normalizing the audio. The last step, is converting the files to OGG.

Answer (score 0):

using peak normalisation will not guarantee you consistent loudness, obviously.. I use Adobe Audition 3.0 to do this batch task.. volume normalised 18,500 MP3s recently, this way..

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Audition/3.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7de8.html